# Convert Weeknum to Date in powerquery in excel

Tags: excel, powerquery

i need edit convert many date with weeknum to date but problem is format.
I recived date in format W19.2023; W20.2023 .... W14.2024 .... W53.2025 etc. it forecast
and i need create table with classic date. I know how can do this in excel but ist add one step.
For me will be perfect when i copy only data to excel and in powerquery can i do all steps

in excel i do it like this:

```
=MIN(DATE(RIGHT(N1;4)+1;1;0);DATE(RIGHT(N1;4);1;1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(RIGHT(N1;4);1;1);2)+MID(N1;2;2)*7)
```

Comment: There are various ways of defining weeknumber. How is yours defined?

Comment: Did either of these two answers solve your question ? If so, please mark one of them as accepted

Answer (score 0):

I did this the long way, because it wasn't quite ISO and I couldnt decide what it was. You can try this in PowerQuery

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

process= (DATE as text)=>
    // DATE format = Wxx.YYYY
    let End = #date(Number.From(Text.End(DATE,4)),12,31),
    First = #date(Number.From(Text.End(DATE,4)),1,1),
    DOW= (1+Date.DayOfWeek(First,Day.Monday)),
    Custom= Number.From(Text.Range(DATE,1,2))*7,
    upwith= Date.AddDays(First,Custom-DOW),
    out = if upwith<End then upwith else End
    in out,

#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Date2", each process([DATE]),type date)
in  #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your formula, you are interpreting WeekNumber in accordance with the original Excel Weeknumber algorithm, with the first day of the week being a Monday.

In that algorithm

- Week 1 always contains January 1
- The week begins on a Monday
- The last week ends on December 31
- Your formula is displaying the End of the Week Date

A Power Query custom function to convert a string in the format of `Www.yyyy` to the last day of the relevant week:

```
(Www.yyyy)=>

let 

//Split the string into weeknumber and year
    split = Text.SplitAny(Www.yyyy,"W."),

//Convert the year and weeknumber to Numbers
    yr = Number.From(split{2}),
    wn = Number.From(split{1}),

//First week of the year is the week that includes Jan 1
    #"First Week" = Date.StartOfWeek(#date(yr,1,1), Day.Monday),

//Add the number of weeks to the first week
//  Also adjust to the Last day of the week as per your Excel formula
    #"Last Date" = Date.EndOfWeek(Date.AddWeeks(#"First Week",(wn-1)),Day.Monday),

//Adjust to exclude running over the end of the year
    #"The Date" = List.Min({#"Last Date", Date.EndOfYear(#date(yr,1,1))})
    
in 
    #"The Date"
```

In your main function, you could add a custom column with the formula:

```
fnDateFromExcelWeekNum([Week])
```

where `Week` represents your column of `Www.yyyy` values.

[image]